# when compare by id is used in Python? Dictionary key comparison?

Tags: python

What does this mean?

> The only types of values not acceptable as dictionary keys are values containing lists or dictionaries or other mutable types that are compared by value rather than by object identity, the reason being that the efficient implementation of dictionaries requires a key’s hash value to remain constant.

I think even for tuples, comparison will happen by value.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with a mutable object as a key is that when we use a dictionary, we rarely want to check identity. For example, when we use a dictionary like this:

```
a = "bob"
test = {a: 30}
print(test["bob"])
```

We expect it to work - the second string `"bob"` may not be the same as `a`, but it is the same value, which is what we care about. This works as any two strings that equate will have the same hash, meaning that the `dict` (implemented as a hashmap) can find those strings very efficiently.

The issue comes into play when we have a list as a key, imagine this case:

```
a = ["bob"]
test = {a: 30}
print(test[["bob"]])
```

We can't do this any more - the comparison won't work as the hash of a list is not based on it's value, but rather the instance of the list (aka `(id(a) != id(["bob"))`).

Python has the choice of making the list's hash change (undermining the efficiency of a hashmap) or simply comparing on identity (which is useless in most cases). Python disallows these specific mutable keys to avoid subtle but common bugs where people expect the values to be equated on value, rather than identity.

Comment: -1 No, that's not the problem. You can have a mutable object with a consistent hash, you just can't put the mutable state into the hash. The most common and most generally useful hash function obeying that restriction is the identity hash function, i.e. a function of `id(self)`. And of course then equality has to be defined as identity as well, and only *then* mutable containers become a problem because we generally want to compare them by value, not by identity.

Comment: @delnan That was the point I was trying to make - I appear to have not made it clear what was important, I'll try to clear it up.

Comment: Removed my downvote, though I still lament that your answer gives the impression that mutable objects *in general* can't be dictionary keys.

Comment: @delnan I added some to the end to try and make that clearer.

Comment: Is the following inference from your answers correct?              " For mutable types, python implementation cannot create hash/unique value. Incase if implementation is modified to use id() to create the hash/unique value and allows usage of mutable types as dictionary keys, then compare by id will be used in the first of the three checks (the hash, then the values) . In no other case compare by id is used by python implementation"

Comment: @user1689963: Still not quite right. It's up to each type to define how it's hashed. For lists, it's part of the definition that two exact copies compare equal; therefore, they have to have equal hashes; therefore the implementation cannot use id to create their hashes; therefore, because they're mutable, their hashes are not consistent. If you remove the "copies compare equal" feature you can hash by id, which never changes; if you remove the "mutable" feature a hash by value never changes; but when both apply (as with list) there's no way to create an unchanging hash.

Comment: @user1689963: To reword things slightly: "For mutable types where copies must compare equal, python cannot create a unique hash value. If the type were changed to remove the copies-compare-equal rule, it would be possible to define a reasonable hash function based on id, which would never change, and therefore the type could be used as a dict key." (As for the last sentence, that's just not true; there are lots of types that are compared by id, and many of these are hashed by id, and therefore legal dict keys.)

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for making it more clear. In general, hash and eq should be working on same data. For lists, eq uses the values for comparison and since the values can change hash is not provided by implementation. May be the case is similar for any non-user defined mutable structure. My last sentence is not correct during garbage collection and User-defined classes which use id for their default hash and eq methods. Please correct me or suggest if anything else is missing.

Comment: I think you've pretty much got it. What's specifically not allowed is having a mutable hash. This happens only if you use mutable value in `__hash__`. The only common way for mutable types to avoid using mutable value in `__hash__` is to use nothing but their `id` for hashing, and in almost every case such types also use nothing but their `id` for `__cmp__`/`__eq__`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation mixes together two different things: mutability, and value-comparable. Let's separate them out.

- Immutable objects that compare by identity are fine. The identity can
  never change, for any object.
- Immutable objects that compare by value are fine. The value can never
  change for an immutable object. This includes tuples.
- Mutable objects that compare by identity are fine. The identity can
  never change, for any object.
- Mutable objects that compare by value are not acceptable. The value
  can change for a mutable object, which would make the dictionary
  invalid.

Meanwhile, your wording isn't quite the same as Mapping Types ([4.10 in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) or [5.8 in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), both of which say:

> A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.

Anyway, the key point here is that the rule is "not hashable"; "mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity)" is just to explain things a little further. It isn't strictly true that comparing by object identity and hashing by object identity are always the same (the only thing that's required is that if id is equal, the hash is equal).

The part about "efficient implementation of dictionaries" from the version you posted just adds to the confusion (which is probably why it's not in the reference documentation). Even if someone came up with an efficient way to deal with storing lists as dict keys tomorrow, the language doesn't allow it.

Comment: The efficient implementation is important as that's the reason for the restriction. If someone found a way to perform efficient lookups without a consistent hash, the implementation would likely be changed.

Comment: @Lattyware: Well, even if such a discovery happened, 4.x dictionaries would probably allow arbitrary keys, but I doubt they'd change 2.x, and likely wouldn't even change 3.x. It would mandate a particular (and likely complicated) implementation across all Pythons, the transparent mappings to Java/.NET/ObjC/etc. hashmaps would be broken, the rules for JSON encoding would change, etc. At any rate, it clearly gets in the way of explaining what should be a pretty simple rule, or the OP wouldn't have been confused. It's not that it's not worth mentioning anywhere, just not there.

Answer (score 0):

A hash is way of calculating an unique code for an object, this code always the same for the same object. `hash('test')` for example is `2314058222102390712`, so is a = 'test'; `hash(a)` = `2314058222102390712`.

Internally a dictionary value is searched by the hash, not by the variable you specify. A list is mutable, a hash for a list, if it where defined, would be changing whenever the list changes. Therefore python's design does not hash lists. Lists therefore can not be used as dictionary keys.

Tuples are immutable, therefore tubles have hashes e.G. `hash((1,2))` = `3713081631934410656`. one could compare whether a tuple `a` is equal to the tuple `(1,2)` by comparing the hash, rather than the value. This would be more efficient as we have to compare only one value instead of two.

Comment: Actually, comparing the hashes is less efficient - you have to do three checks (the hash, then the values) - the hash being the same **does not** tell you the values are the same - just that they could be. Of course, in the grand scheme it increases efficiency by making the initial check very simple (when going through a data structure, you know you will get a lot more false hits than positive ones).

Comment: This answers (and very nicely) everything except the part the OP asked about: The reason lists can't be used as keys is because they're mutable _and_ their equality and hashes are based on their values. If they were mutable but their equality and hashes were id-based, it would be acceptable. The question was about that distinction as much as the mutable/immutable distinction, and the answer is that only when it's both mutable and value-based that there's a problem.